# Extract JSON data from Javascript response using python

Tags: javascript, python, json, extract

In scraping a website, I am getting given javascript code as a response from the server.

```
document.write("<script src='/src/one/data.cached.js?ver=9153'></script>");
amorphic.setApplication('one');
amorphic.setSchema(
  {
    "Address": {"customer": 1},
    "Person": {"customer": 1},
    "Phone": {"customer": 1}
  }
);
```

---

So, how can I extract this json data from the response using python?

```
  {
    "Address": {"customer": 1},
    "Person": {"customer": 1},
    "Phone": {"customer": 1}
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Comment: you can use regex to remove unwanted text and extract dictinoary or there must be option for to extract response data directly

Comment: did you try just to call dict on your object? like this `dict(your_object)`. Also, try `your_object['Address']`

Comment: What you're showing looks like JSONP, not JSON. That's usually only done from client-side code, server code can request ordinary JSON.

Comment: @ettanany , I am getting the json data wrapped inside a javascript object. I don't think that I can get the json data directly by using your_object['Address'].

Comment: I can not understand! what's `helloWorld.LoremIpsum` in your case? Can you access `{"Address": ...}` in your javascript code? Are you trying to use Python in your frontend application or calling an API?

Comment: No, now it's a Javascript program.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to search for the call to `amorphic.setSchema`, and then extract the object literal in the argument.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar ... can you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: www.regular-expression.info is a great site with a regular expression tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally extracted the required data from the response using Regular expression operations - [`re package`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

*Seems like this is the only way to extract json data from javascript response.*

Heartily thanks to [Prashant Puri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5702489/prashant-puri) and [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for their quick and great help.